# Navigation to the webpage was canceled getting message in asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, networking, webforms

When i am download aspx page to image format then getting below error message in downloaded image, but local host every think working fine only when upload into live server then downloaded file is download but inside file message is coming not my aspx data showing.

`Navigation to the webpage was canceled`

below is my downloaded image file with message

[image]

I am tring to take screen short of the web page using win form WebBrowser control below is my code

Below is code assigning URL to textbox for downloading

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   txtweburl.Text = "http://example.com/dicdownload.aspx?VisitedId=DIC_V00025";

 }
```

Below is code for generate screeen using thread

```
  protected void btnscreenshot_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //  btnscreenshot.Visible = false;
    allpanels.Visible = true;
    Thread thread = new Thread(GenerateThumbnail);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();

}

private void GenerateThumbnail()
{
    //  btnscreenshot.Visible = false;
    WebBrowser webrowse = new WebBrowser();
    webrowse.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    webrowse.AllowNavigation = true;
    string url = txtweburl.Text.Trim();
    webrowse.Navigate(url);
    webrowse.Width = 1400;
    webrowse.Height = 50000;

    webrowse.DocumentCompleted += webbrowse_DocumentCompleted;
    while (webrowse.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

In below code I am saving the image file after download deleting the same file

```
        private void webbrowse_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // btnscreenshot.Visible = false;
    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/ImageFiles/");

    WebBrowser webrowse = sender as WebBrowser;
    //Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(webrowse.Width, webrowse.Height);

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(webrowse.Width, webrowse.Height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);

    webrowse.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, webrowse.Bounds);


    string Systemimagedownloadpath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Systemimagedownloadpath"].ToString();
    string fullOutputPath = Systemimagedownloadpath + Request.QueryString["VisitedId"].ToString() + ".png";
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(fullOutputPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);


    // You should put more appropriate MIME type as per your file time - perhaps based on extension
    Response.ContentType = "application/octate-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Request.QueryString["VisitedId"].ToString() + ".png");
    // Start pushing file to user, IIS will do the streaming.
    Response.TransmitFile("~/ImageFiles/" + Request.QueryString["VisitedId"].ToString() + ".png");
    Response.Flush();//Won't get error with Flush() so use this Instead of End()
    var filePath = Server.MapPath("~/ImageFiles/" + Request.QueryString["VisitedId"].ToString() + ".png");
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }


}
```

Local host everything working fine but when it is in live downloading the image with that message

I have check with below solution also

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/967941/navigation-is-canceled-when-you-browse-to-web-pages-that-are-in-differ

[IIS configuration: Navigation to the webpage was canceled when converting page to PDF using SautinSoft.PdfVision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921978/iis-configuration-navigation-to-the-webpage-was-canceled-when-converting-page-t/21984994)

Comment: My network team is saying its code error but i told them this network security issue, can tell me exact what is the issue means what type of permissions issue. @RamAnugandula

Comment: But code is working fine in local host. @RamAnugandula

Comment: This protected mode is enabled setting i have to do in server system  or client machine, client machine already did but not coming. @RamAnugandula

Comment: We are in windows 10 machine and EDge browser is available. @RamAnugandula

Comment: Using the WebBrowser control from an ASP.NET application that will be hosted from IIS is not a good idea. Even if you can get it to work sometimes it is almost guaranteed to break under any kind of load. https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/238425/info-wininet-not-supported-for-use-in-services

Comment: But local host working fine na, please suggest alternative solution, i know it is taking loading time for download, but local system and from local iis its working fine to me. Only the problem in live server. @ser469104

Comment: There are third party tools such as Kapow that were made to deal with server side website navigation, data extraction, taking screenshots etc. Using windows client components such as Office automation or the web browser control is a bad idea. You can probably get it to work, intermittently and with no load on the server. But it will start breaking when there is load on the server. The fact that it works on your local machine means nothing. Your local machine is a single user machine, the environment these components were designed for. A deployed server environment is not.

Comment: If i will purchase https certification then it will work? because its like local host. @user469104

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At my case we have to do three setting then my download part working perfectly fine

1) SSL Certificates

2) My Network Team Upgrade lowest version IIS to IIS10

3) Set the IIS to 64 bit version

Answer (score 3):

First, try to reset Internet Explorer settings.

Add a site to your trusted sites.

- In Internet Explorer, select Tools > Internet Options from the menu
  at the top.
- The 
  Internet Options window will appear. Select the
  Security tab. 
  Then click on the 
  Trusted sites icon.

[image]

- Click the Sites button.

[image]

- The 
  Trusted sites window will open. Type the URL of the site in the website box as shown. Click 
  Add. Then add an ”
  s” after the
  http (i.e. make the address look like: ”

https
://trusted.website.com“). Click 
Add again.

**Be
 certain that you do NOT check the box for 
Require server verification (https). Check it twice!**

- Click the  Close button.
- With  Trusted sites still selected, click ” Custom Level“.

[image]

- The
  Security Settings – Trusted Sites Zone window will open. Scroll down until you see ”
  Display mixed content“. Select 
  Enable.

[image]

- Back on the
  Internet Options window, click 
  OK to save the changes. Try the site again to see if it works better with these settings.

Comment: Thanks, i will check and update you answer. @Jalpa Panchal

Comment: Can you tell me i have to do this setting where?  i have to do in live server system or client machine where the user will access the download functionality. @Jalpa Panchal

Comment: could you share where you get this error message at server-side or the client-side?

Comment: See i will tell you clearly from lohost url (URL:http://localhost:57052) working fine download file with correct data, The problem is when i am dowloading file from live website url(www.myweb.com/download.aspx) then in this file i am getting that message, i am using that application then its client site issue na. @Jalpa Panchal

Comment: did you try any other browser?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that solved for me was to disable firewall on server where you are hosting RDL reports.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still trying to figure this out. For me it worked after I set `webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;` in my code. Do give it a try.

Comment: where do you set this config in code?

Comment: In the InitializeComponent() of your designer code